# To date, what are the most powerful non-fusion Yu-Gi-Oh monsters and/or their attacks?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I was rewatching the original Yu-Gi-Oh anime, it occured to me that it varied *widely* in some instances from the actual trading card game. Between Exodia, the Blue Eyes White dragon, the Dark Magician, the Egyptian God Cards and high level fusions, there are a lot of monsters with massive attack power based around their life points.

In the real life TCG, most of those creatures have to be special summoned, have conditions which give them special abilities or affects in matches, or have limits, though.

It's been a while since I played, and I'm well aware that most advantages depend on certain factors, such as Deck type, Specialty, Field, relation to Trap and Magic Cards...... but there are some pretty strong [what we used to term as "beat stick"] monsters that could be used.

I was curious as to **What were the strongest real-life Yugioh monsters in the TCG, and what [if any] their anime or manga attacks may have been?**

To narrow this, I'm looking specifically at **non-fusion, non special summons type monsters.** To account for type differences, the top most powerful monster from each attribute [DARK,LIGHT,DIVINE,EARTH,FIRE,WATER,WIND,LAUGHTER] can be suggested.

The question is specific to series 1, but if any experts wish to answer for following series, it would be an interesting read.

Comment: If your primary focus is on real-life cards, then this is more suitable to Board & Card Games.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous cards that aren't fusion monsters whose ATK points are considerable.
The lineup of "Black Luster Soldiers" All have 3000 ATK and are not fusion monsters.
"Sorcerer of Dark Magic", "Masked Beast des Guardius" 3200 ATK.
Egyptian god cards and many ritual monsters.